# Is it good practice to use another attribute to identify derived class than class name

Tags: java, oop

Lets suppose I have base class as

```
Class BaseClass {
   List<String> attributes;
}

Class DerivedClass1 extends BaseClass {
}

Class DerivedClass2 extends BaseClass {
}
```

Now  value of attributes depend on chosen derived class. And these attributes are needed to be stored in DB.

There are two ways I can think of:

1. Store attributes with identifier as className.
2. Create another attribute like category in base class which has to be defined by each child class. And store attributes with corresponding to category.

What you think should be right way to do it and why ?

Comment: Typically speaking, you might start with your DB design _first_ and afterwards create Java objects around it.  Can you clue us in more on the database design?

Comment: The two approaches seem equivalent from a design standpoint. And you did not specify how this would be mapped to database tables (the more interesting part of the design problem, software updates are easier than data migrations). If you are going to use a library to do the DB mapping, take a look at how that library wants to handle this.

Comment: If the class name matters then your class breakdown is wrong.

Comment: DB design has table storing attributes with two columns : category and attributes.
Category will track which class these attributes belong to.

Comment: How about the fields in the subclasses?

Comment: Thilo, are you asking if category identify subclasses also ?

Then you can assume that Base class is abstract class. And category always identify the last derived subclass.